# r keeping only specific digits after the decimal point and printing the number

Tags: r

In R, How can I ensure that i only print 3 characters/numbers after the decimal point?
I thought that format command with nsmall parameter is sufficient but i am not getting required answer

```
> format(0.6791787, nsmall=3)
[1] "0.6791787"
```

I want 0.679

Comment: you would also need `nsmall=3` with `digits=3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sprintf` it would be

```
sprintf("%.3f", 0.6791787)
# [1] "0.679"
```

The number after the `.` and before the `f` is the number of digits to print after the decimal.

Comment: how can i print 0.679 without quotes and the [1]?

Comment: wrap the whole thing in `cat`

Comment: `cat(sprintf("%.3f", 0.6791787))`

Comment: With linefeed: `cat(sprintf("%.3f", 0.6791787),"\n")`.